# How Can I Display a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage etc. within an Android Presentation?

Tags: .net, xamarin, android-fragments, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Forms app targets an exotic multi-screen Android device. I'm trying to display a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage on the secondary screen using Android's MediaRouter. I've been able to display an Android Presentation on the secondary screen using the MediaRouter API, but have been unable to take the next step and swap in my Xamarin.Forms view.

The only way to display a ContentPage within a native Xamarin.Android layout that I'm aware of is to swap out a fragment within the layout for a fragment created using the Xamarin.Forms CreateSupportFragment API, as demonstrated in the official Xamarin.Forms sample, [Native2Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms).

However, that approach uses a FragmentManager to perform the swap. And as far as I can tell, there is no FragmentManager that is able to access items within a layout displayed by a Presentation. As such, it doesn't seem possible to use the "Native2Forms" technique to display a ContentPage on a secondary screen.

So, assume my Presentation displays a layout containing a FrameLayout:

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame_layout" />
```

If I attempt to swap in the Xamarin.Forms ContentPage (I tried obtaining the FragmentManager several ways, including from MainActivity and through CrossCurrentActivity, all with the same result) ..

```
fragmentManager
    .BeginTransaction()
    .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, noteEntryFragment)
    .Commit();
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x7f0900fa (com.myapp.mobileapp:id/fragment_frame_layout) for fragment PageExtensions_EmbeddedSupportFragment{c1a5ea} (a4ea714e-f673-4f4d-b2e2-27cd37bbdf4c) id=0x7f0900fa}'

How does one bridge this gap between native Android and Xamarin.Forms to display a ContentPage in a secondary screen's Presentation? I'll accept any answer that allows me to embed any kind of Xamarin.Forms view.

NOTE: I tried using the [Surface Duo SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dual-screen/android/api-reference/dualscreen-library/) for this instead of the MediaRouter approach, but the secondary screen was not recognized. I was later able to determine that this SDK is specific to  "foldable" devices, and is not usable in a generic multi-display scenario.

Comment: From your description, you want to add ContentPage in Android project , then display this contentpage on secondary screen?

Comment: Precisely. The ContentPage is actually defined in the Forms project. I want to instantiate it in the referencing Android project, or pass it in from the Forms project. The important part is displaying it on the Android device's secondary screen.

Comment: Sounds like you need android code added to [Xamarin.Forms Dual-Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dual-screen/). (I don't know anything about this package.)

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve -- you're referring to the Surface Duo SDK, which I have already eliminated as a potential solution (see note at the end of my question).

Comment: Ah, I did not see that note. As you discovered, it won't work as is. What I meant is that if there is a github with source code for it, then go there, raise an issue that you want it to work on that device, or ask if anyone can add Android code to that SDK. I suspect that X-Forms can't do what you ask, without some low-level assistance. That SDK seems like the right place to get help in adding that assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ToolmarkerSteve, but that SDK is not intended to work in my scenario. The problem is in their documentation, which doesn't make this clear.